# SwiftUI list not updating when the array changes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, swift4

```
VStack(spacing: 0){
    List{
        ForEach(postsData.fetchedPosts, id: \.postID) { post in
            SocialPostView(post: post, showAccount: self.$showAccount, fetchedUser: self.$fetchedUser)
                .padding(.vertical)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .onAppear {
                    self.elementOnAppear(post)
            }
        }
    }
    .pullToRefresh(isShowing: $isShowing) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.isShowing = false
            self.postsData.newFetch = true
            self.postsData.fetchPosts(userInfo: self.userInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

```
private func elementOnAppear(_ post: Post) {
    /* onAppear on the view is called when a view appears on screen.
     elementOnAppear asks the view model if the element is the last one.
     If so, we ask the view model to fetch new data. */
    
    if self.postsData.isLastPostInList(post: post) {
        self.postsData.fetchPosts(userInfo: self.userInfo)
    }
}
```

When each list element appears, it checks if it's the last element in the array. If it is, it fetches more from Firestore and updates `fetchedPosts`. However, when the array updates, the List is not updated, so no new elements show up.

This is the ObservableObject, which publishes the array.

```
class SocialObservable: ObservableObject{
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    
    @Published var fetchedPosts = [Post]()
    
    @Published var lastSnap : DocumentSnapshot?
    @Published var reachedEnd = false
    
    var currentListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    var newFetch = false {
        willSet{
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    init(userInfo: UserData){
        print(userInfo.uid)
        fetchPosts(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
    
    func fetchPosts(userInfo: UserData){
        var first: Query?
        
        if lastSnap == nil || newFetch {
            //not last snapshot, or just updated feed
            
            if newFetch{
                newFetch.toggle()
                fetchedPosts = [] // clean up if new fetch
            }
            
            first = db.collection("posts")
                .whereField("availability", arrayContains: userInfo.uid)
                .order(by: "date", descending: true)
                .limit(to: 1)
        }
        else {
            first = db.collection("posts")
                .whereField("availability", arrayContains: userInfo.uid)
                .order(by: "date", descending: true)
                .start(afterDocument: lastSnap!)
                .limit(to: 1)
        }

        first?.getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }
            let doc = snapshot.documents.map({postFromDB(obj: $0.data(), id: $0.documentID)})
            
            doc.map({print($0.postID)})
            // append to fetched posts
            self.fetchedPosts = self.fetchedPosts + doc
            print(self.fetchedPosts.count)
            
            //prepare for the next fetch
            guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else {
                // the collection is empty. no data fetched
                self.reachedEnd = true
                return
            }
            // save last snapshot
            self.lastSnap = lastSnapshot
        })
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    func isLastPostInList(post: Post) -> Bool {
        return post.postID == fetchedPosts.last?.postID
    }
    
    
}
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Is `postsData` defined as: `@ObservedObject let postsData: SocialObservable`? - it needs to be an `@ObservedObject` for a view to refresh due to updates. Btw, if you're changing a `@Published` property, you don't need to also use `objectWillChange.send`

Comment: Hmm I changed it to `@ObservedObject var postsData = SocialObservable(userInfo: UserData())`, but it's still the same problem... For that `objectWillChange.send`, sure I can change it to a @published property - I just want the view to be able to toggle newFetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things

```
class SocialObservable: ObservableObject{
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    // let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()     // << remove this
    
    // ...
    
    var newFetch = false {
        willSet{
            self.objectWillChange.send()    // ObservableObject has default
        }
    }

    // ...
```

and on update modify published on main queue

```
    doc.map({print($0.postID)})
    // append to fetched posts
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.fetchedPosts = self.fetchedPosts + doc
    }
    print(self.fetchedPosts.count)
```